# How can I troubleshoot a 404 error on my subdomain when my main domain works fine for the same app?

Tags: http-status-code-404, subdomain, cpanel, shared-hosting

my subdomain can not read file in public and return a 404 error

hosted a vue js app on my subdomain but return me a 404 error but when i host the same app on the main domain it work, i think there is a problem preventing subdomain reading the files